# pandas to csv without converting object to scientific notation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scientific-notation, read-sql

df['Acolumn']='85236E106'

When i df.to_csv('file') it outputs as '8.523600000000001e+110'

how can i convert to csv and leave the value as '85236E106' ?

I tried:

- float_format='%f' and output = a really long float instead of '85236E106'
- float_format='{:f}'.format and output = a really long float instead of '85236E106'
- df['col']=str(df['col']) and output = '8.523600000000001e+110'
- df['col']=df['col'].astype(str) and output = '8.523600000000001e+110'
- encoding='utf-8' and output = no difference
- Column::text in read_sql and output = doesn't work
- CONVERT(text, Id) in read_sql and output = doesn't work
- CAST(Id AS varchar) in read_sql and output = doesn't work
- coerce_float=False in read_sql and output = doesn't work

Comment: I can't reproduce with the column being a string column as in `df['Acolumn']='85236E106'`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the file again and i'm not sure why df['Acolumn']='85236E106' is now not being converted to scientific notation.
I'm using to_csv with only index=False as parameters.
However I've added dtype={'Acolumn': pd.StringDtype()} to pd.read_sql_query just incase.